# How to concatenate tables from different directories with only one header

Tags: bash, cat

I have several directories ("amazon", "niger",...), in which I have several subdirectories ("gfdl", "hadgem",...), in which I also have several sub-directories ("rcp8p5", "rcp4p5",...). In this last subdirectories I always have two folders ("historical", "projected") that contain thousand of tables having the same frame. Therefore, I would like to concatenate those tables (present in the two folders of the last sub-directories) in order to have just one big table with only one header and not an header each time that a table has been concatenate. Does anyone knows how to do that?

I am currently using the following loop structure:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage:cat_dat dirname

data_dir=/scratch/01/stevens/climate_scenario/river

for river in tagus
  do
   for gcm in gfdl-esm2m hadgem2-es
     do
      for scenario in rcp8p5 rcp4p5 rcp6p0 rcp2p6
        do
          find "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}" name \*.dat -exec cat {} + >> "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}.dat"
      done
   done
done
```

but I can´t get rid of the header with that! Any helps is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close. Rather than `cat` you can use `awk` to skip the first line and print the remaining.

```
find "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}" name \*.dat -exec awk 'NR > 1' {} + >> "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}.dat"
```

This is a pretty empty `awk` script because it relies on the default behavior. No BEGIN or END and use the default action which is print.

I use `awk` more frequently which is why I suggested it but you could also get the same effect with other tools:

With **sed**:

```
sed 1d
```

With **tail**:

```
tail -n +2
```

Of course you could also use perl, python, or another language.

Comment: `sed 1d` seems simpler and shorter than `awk 'NR > 1'`

Comment: Thanks! I am now really close to what I searched for, but still I would like to keep the header on the first line. 'sed' delete all the header and 'tail' provide a strange one "==> /home/stevens/climate_analysis/amazon/gfdl-esm2m/rcp4p5/gfdl-esm2m_historical_amazon/10126basz.dat <==
". Do you have any idea how to keep the header in first line off the output table?

Comment: before the find add the header from one of the files: `head -1 ${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}/historical/some_file_name.foo >  ${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}.dat`